# Underwater protection for lenses

Tags: lens, underwater, camera-cases

I've got a Sony A6000 camera and planning to get Nauticam underwater housing for it.

I've noticed the box is often shown (in pictures, videos and such) with a lens, but I can't seem to find any details whatsoever regarding the lens underwater protection.

With that in mind, I'd like to ask: If I've got a decent Box and have the means to protect the camera underwater, the lenses aren't IN the box how are they protected?

I mean do I need special underwater lenses or are there specific cases for lenses too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I've got a decent Box and have the means to protect the camera underwater, the lenses aren't IN the box how are they protected?

Underwater housings completely contain both the body and the lens. It looks like the Nauticam setup has various lens housings that mate with the body housing, and you'll certainly need both parts.

Comment: Looks like a bit more than an additional part for the lens housing. Maybe add a link to [the Nauticam PDF Port System guide](http://www.nauticam.com/images/attach/dslr_port_system_chart.pdf) for which bits are needed for which lens?